# How many eigenvectors have this matrix?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am trying to calculate eigenvalues and eigenvectors of this matrix

$$\frac12\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1&-1&1&-1\\
1&1&-1&-1\\
1&-1&-1&1  
\end{pmatrix}?$$

Determinat is $\frac{1}{16}(\lambda^2-4)^2$ and it should have two eigenvalues $2$ and $-2$. I also need eigenvectors. I decided to check it by [wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2F2*%7B%7B1-lambda,1,1,1%7D,%7B1,-1-lambda,1,-1%7D,%7B1,1,-1-lambda,-1%7D,%7B1,-1,-1,1-lambda%7D%7D). However, there are 4 eigenvectors, I have only two. Where I made mistake?

Comment: You also have $4$ eigenvalues: $2,2,-2-2$.

Comment: One eigenvalue can give you more than one eigenvector

Comment: You must operate to realize in your example

Comment: The eigenvalues are $\pm 1$, not $\pm 2$ - note the factor of $1/2$.

Comment: @Math1000 are you sure? I think it is 2,-2

Comment: The spectrum is $\pm 1$. Note that $A A^T = A^T A$, so the matrix is normal and has a full set of eigenvectors.

Comment: I suppose that you’re really looking for more *linearly independent* eigenvectors, since you already have an infinite number of eigenvectors—every nonzero scalar multiple of the two that you’ve found is also an eigenvector of this matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that also the identity $I$ has $1$ eigenvalues but $4$ *independent* eigenvectors.

In your case we have 2 eigenvalues with **algebraic multiplicity** equal to 2 but the key point for eigenvectors is the **geometric multiplicity** of each eigenvalue, that is $n-r$ with $r=$rank of  $(A-\lambda I)$.

In this case, if $rank(A-\lambda I)=2$ for each eigenvalue we can find $2 $ corresponding eigenvectors by the solution of $(A-\lambda I)x=0$.

Comment: @amd Yes of course! I used a really bad term, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The system $$(A-\lambda I)V =0 $$ has more than one solution for $\lambda =2$  or$\lambda =-2$  .

Comment: The system has exactly one solution for $\lambda = \pm 2$ :-).